# Missing permission for GUI application to upload system snapshots

Tags: permissions, backup, google-drive, gksudo

I'm using Timeshift to create snapshots of my system and I'm trying to upload these huge files onto Google Drive using the Application Insync.

The problem is that the application does not have the proper permissions to upload certain files. Being still new to Ubuntu, I'm not sure how to handle this. Coming from Windows, my approach would be to try to start Insync with sudo.  A quick research revealed that there used to be a command 'gksudo' for that purpose - but most people discouraged using sudo like that. My only other idea would be to change the permission of all the files in the snapshot, but that doesn't seem like a good idea either.

What is the proper way to approach such a problem in general?